# How do I set up NetBeans to access projects where permissions do not match my current user?

Tags: linux, netbeans, permissions, netbeans-6.9

I'm trying to use NetBeans 6.9. The application can't access file located in the apache root folder; My project is located on the same machine--a test LAMP server. The apache root has owner root and group apache. But NetBeans has the user privileges of the current user.

The application does not present any solution automatically. I've gone through the FAQ and searched the wiki and I can't find a help doc or post to explain how to use NetBeans with Linux's permissions system.

My framework projects require directory 744 and file 644 permissions, so I can't solve NetBeans RW requirement with groups.

I've worked around this using the NetBeans `--userdir /root` option. It allows me to start the application as root user and therefore have superuser access. However, it's not working to keep NetBeans preferences. I have to reload the project and presumably overwrite the NetBeans meta files from the last time I added the project.

What am I missing? How do I set user permissions using NetBeans?

Comment: No one using NetBeans have this problem? Great! Then it should be an easy answer. I posted it at [NetBeans](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=41666&highlight=) forum, but not even a, "You're a netbeans newbie :P"...

Comment: i have recently started using netbeans on ubuntu 12.04 .. and i came across the same problem .. i wanted to create a PHP project from existing files, which exist on our server .. the best solution i found was to sudo run netbeans .. but that is not a good practice .. plz tell me if you have found a better solution yourself ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised there are no replies from peeps using netbeans to manage projects over a network (located somewhere else)...I ended up with a non-netbeans solution with permissions on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your current user (the one who starts Netbeans) to the group that own the project files.

For instance: (in super user)

```
usermod -G -a apache <myuser>
```

Note: Don't forget to login/logout to apply group changes